# What are the topological properties of the Cantor set if a point is added at the center of every missing segment?

Tags: general-topology, cantor-set

> What are the topological properties of the Cantor set if a point is added at the center of every empty segment?

Suppose that when the segment $\left(\frac13,\frac23\right)$ is deleted from $[0,1]$, a point is also not deleted at its centre $\frac12$ and the process then proceeds by repetition (i.e. deleting all but a central point at each step) as in the normal construction.

What are the topological properties of this set?

It's easy to see that at least an infinite, binary rooted tree of points is added.  But what about the limit points?  Is it still totally disconnected and measure zero?

Comment: the measure stays zero because you only add countably many points

Comment: I have no idea what you mean when you ask "But what about the limit points?".

Comment: @EricWofsey I intend a construction in which there is one extra isolated point for every pair of isolated points in the standard construction. The points added must therefore be uncountable in number.

Comment: You’re saying that the complement of the Cantor set consists of uncountably many disjoint open intervals. That doesn’t sound right to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result is that you've added countably many isolated points to the Cantor set. In particular, this set is still totally disconnected and measure zero.

Comment: This is a helpful perspective, but I was interested in the case in which $\{(\frac13,\frac12),(\frac12,\frac23)\}$ is deleted and so on, suggesting the new points are as uncountable as the standard Cantor set.

Comment: In the standard construction of the Cantor set, countably many intervals are removed (one at the first stage, two at the second stage, four at the third stage, etc.). You leave one isolated point in each interval, resulting in countably many isolated points. What's uncountable in the Cantor set is the points *left over* after removing the intervals. @samerivertwice

Comment: yeah, I guess I get it now.